# Javascript Regex .test(): Returning true for a double space (or more) in the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is to return 'true' for a valid string, which in this case is a string that starts with a letter, then has any combination of letters and numbers and spaces, but no consecutive spaces.

I've tried several combinations, with the following 'prefix':

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

This works just fine for the 'start with a letter' and 'combinations of letters and numbers', but I am having trouble adding the regex to match a space, and only a single space.

For example:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$|[\s{0,1}]
```

doesn't work. It will return true for "asdasdasd 3333$", among other things.

It is if I am trying to force the logic:

```
if (firstLetter != letter){
    return false;
}
else{
    var spaceFound = false;
    for ( var int = 0; int < individualLetters.length; int++) {
            if (individualLetters[int] == space){
                  if (spaceFound == true){
                         return false; 
                  }
                  else {
                          spaceFound = true;     
                  }  
            }
        if(individualLetters[int] != letterOrNumber){
                      return false;
            }
            else{
                spaceFound = false;
                continue; 
            }  
    }
}
```

However I think I am missing a fundamental understanding on regex. Any way, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here <del>are two different flavors</del> is one flavor:

```
function test(s) {
    return /^[A-Z]([A-Z]|\d| (?! ))*$/i.test(s);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HCNDD/2

Comment: I think the top one works correctly, but the bottom one fails for the case `"A B"`

Comment: @ninjagecko, @Milimetric: Guys, have you actually tried it? `"A B"` seems to work for me on Chrome, FF and IE: http://jsfiddle.net/HCNDD/1/

Comment: The bottom one is wrong and fails in Chrome, please remove it. You may have tried `test1` by mistake.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Ah! Stupid copy/paste error in the test cases. OK, bottom one removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
/^[a-z]( ?[a-z0-9])*$/i
```

It matches your `[a-z]` then `[a-z0-9]` again and again...

Comment: Shorthand for `\s{0,1}` -> `\s?`

Comment: Also make sure you include the `i` flag for case-insensitive matching.

Comment: `\s` matches tabs as well, thus this would incorrect say `'A\t'` is true. And the fact that you are using `+` means you insist the second character must be alphanumeric, which is not the case.

Comment: The tabs were intentional due to the OP putting `\s`.  Fixed 2nd char issue by flipping whitespace to beginning of the repeating set.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise from trying to do everything in a regular expression; they are, after all, not as powerful as the language you are coding in. The following one-liner is not verbose at all, and makes your intent clear:

```
query.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/) && !query.match(/  /)
```

You may need to cast to a Boolean(...). See note at end of answer for a single elegant boolean expression.

A test suite is probably what you want:

```
function test(query) {
    /*
     *  "My goal is to return 'true' for a valid string, which in this 
     *   case is a string that starts with a letter, then has any combination 
     *   of letters and numbers and spaces, but no consecutive spaces."
     */
    return (query.match(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/) && !query.match(/  /)) == true;
}

[
    ['Z', true],
    [' ', false],
    ['_', false],
    ['9', false],
    ['A ', true],
    ['A  ', false],
    ['a\t', false],
    ['a*', false],
    ['a b C02 4', true],
    ['a b C02 4 ', true],
    ['a b C02 4  ', false],
    ['a b C02  4 ', false],
    ['a  b C02 4 ', false],
    ['a _', false],
    ['a  ', false]
].map(function(pair){
    if ( test(pair[0]) != pair[1] )
        console.log('FAILED TEST:', pair);
});
```

Of course, the definition of what is a 'letter' can change if you're not working with ascii, but for example, unicode with international characters. If you desire unicode support, see [Javascript + Unicode regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode)

---

**Edit!**

If you really want to use a regular expression, it turns out if your regex engine supports negative lookaheads `(?!BADPATTERN)`, then you can translate `PATTERN without SUBPATTERN within` to `(?!.*SUBPATTERN)PATTERN`. This information thanks to a comment by Tim Pietzcker.

Thus if you really wanted a single regular expression, you could do:

```
function test(query) {
    /*
     *  "My goal is to return 'true' for a valid string, which in this 
     *   case is a string that starts with a letter, then has any combination 
     *   of letters and numbers and spaces, but no consecutive spaces."
     */
    return Boolean( query.match(/^[A-Za-z](?!.*  )[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$/) );
    //                      START|[alpha  [alnums/spcs without |END
    //                           |       ] any ^^double spcs  ]|
}
```

And since we wrote our test battery above, we can easily check to see that it passes with flying colors. I think there's another answer (only one) which manages to correctly do this by putting the negative lookahead attached to every character (which only works because the regex is of the form `[charset]*`, but is still valid). Anyway this is the general way to do it.

Comment: nah, 'cause it wouldn't match the numbers

Comment: You might consider \w instead of [a-zA-Z] so things like hyphen are permitted - and it's fewer characters to type. :-)

Comment: I think \w corresponds to [A-Za-z0-9_], and may have used it, but that would have violated the specification as given by the original poster. Thanks for mentioning for the record though!

Comment: +1, a single regex is also going to be more prone to really messing with the backtracking regex engine.  And it's less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't negate groups, so you can't forbid 2 spaces with just one regexp.

I didn't get the motivation for your second regexp, but the reason it doesn't work is that you're allowing a string with a single space no matter where it occurs; ^ matches the start of the string and $ matches the end, so you're not actually writing a prefix, but a whole string; I.e. If

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$|[\s{0,1}]
```

means anything, it means

- the whole string is a letter followed by any number of letters or digits

OR

- the string has a space somewhere in it

Possibly what you want is

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/.test(s) && !/  /.test(s)
```

Comment: Yes you can forbid 2 spaces: `\s(?!\s)` -- means: Match whitespace only if it's not followed by a whitespace.

Comment: You're not paying attention. Not including is not the same as forbidding. Forbidding means disallowing something which would otherwise be allowed. In a regexp, it would mean have a means of saying 'this sequence cannot occur'. You can do that for single characters but not for groups. You should have known it since you put forbid in quotes yourself. This is a completely unjustified down vote and I resent that.

Comment: That's close, Ates, but still not it. It is a match for a space not followed by another space, in the engines that allow it, but not a forbidding of two spaces.

Comment: "not including is not the same as forbidding" How so?  If I give you a regex that 100% of the time does ___not___ match a string with two spaces, the logic ___is___ forbidding two spaces.  The `-1` was for "you can't forbid 2 spaces with just one regexp"

Comment: To illustrate, can you provide me with a regexp that, when people read it aloud, naturally means 'any combination of letters of the alphabet, spaces and common punctuation, but excluding the sequences "oops", " ," and "Poland75"'?

Comment: Your random case doesn't matter.  The point is that you can forbid ___two spaces___, which is what this question was about, and your statement "you can't forbid 2 spaces with just one regexp" is wrong.

Comment: You still don't understand what 'forbid' means. The only reading of my statement that can possibly make it wrong also makes it meaningless, so it could do no harm anyway, even if it weren't explained, which it is. Your vote was rash where a conciliatory edit would have served the community better, and when called on it you have nothing to counter so you push ahead. So now the answer which really explains to the OP why his code wasn't working and provides him with a semantic solution goes to the bottom. Because you insist on giving a self-disqualifying interpretation to one its sentences.

Comment: Wow...  You made an incorrect statement: "You can't forbid 2 spaces with just one regexp" and then continued on to provide two regexes when the poster asked for one.  I downvoted you for that, big deal.  I know what "forbid" means and I'm saying you're wrong.  Your argument is akin to saying that `if(!(foo==bar))` isn't forbidding `foo` from equaling bar because you're using a `==` instead of `!=`.  Besides, the OP didn't use the word "forbid" and why should a grammar have any effect in the simple fact that you ___can___ do what the OP asked in one regex?

Comment: @entonio: Here you go: `^(?:(?!oops| ,|Poland75)[\w\s\p{P}])*$`. (I used `\p{P}` for punctuation which isn't part of JavaScript regexes, but I didn't know what you mean by "common". Feel free to replace it with the characters you want to allow.)

Comment: @Tim: That seems to be the same trick that was used in one of the two correct answers. Unfortunately I don't think this would generalize to arbitrary expressions. For example, I don't think one can write a regular expression of the form "`PATTERN without SUBPATTERN within`" (what I think entonio was trying to say). This works, as you've demonstrated, if PATTERN is of the form `[charset]*`, but if for example one had a sufficiently complicated PATTERN, I don't think this could be done naturally? Please correct me if mistaken. Nevertheless your trick is quite useful, thank you for sharing.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Of course you can to this, just in a different way, for example `^(?!.*SUBPATTERN)PATTERN$` (or, if not matching the entire string, use other anchors like `\b` around the substring.

Comment: THAT IS INGENIOUS... you, sir, are the God of Regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody's making this a lot more difficult than it needs to be.  Try to think in terms of what you want to happen, and let the negatives take care of themselves. Check it out:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

Each time the regex runs out of alphanumeric characters, it tries to match a space followed immediately by another block of alphanumerics.  I don't have to tell it not to match any more spaces because I've already told it what I *do* want to match next.  And when it reaches a point where it can't match an alphanumeric or a space, and it's not at the end of the string, it fails.